# Regexp with slashes and path to files

Tags: regex, bash, parsing, logging

Want to parse some logs, a bit hard.
Logs look like this:

```
/ajax/foto.php?whatever-session-info-here
/edit.php?path=blahblah-imgage-url.jpg
/catalog/whetaever-text-here
/item/whetaever-text-here
/gallery (without slash at the end)
```

So

> /[a-zA-Z-]{0,}/

works good for text between slashes, and i have

```
/catalog/
/item/
```

after regexp work

So question is how to get output for this example that looked like:

```
/ajax/foto.php
/edit.php
/catalog/
/item/
/gallery
```

**ADD**:
found this, need only text betwen first two slashes:

```
/foto/300/b/5/4/19123312.jpg
```

to get /foto/

Comment: You can just use `[^?]*` if you want to match everything up until a potential `?`

Comment: @thatotherguy removal of `whetaever-text-here` in the example is an evidence to the contrary. Seems to be the usual case of "Too hard to specify what I want ==> let's go with no specification ==> here are some examples ==> now let's write a regexp that seems to work".

Comment: Also, I highly recommend to use reference cards such as http://www.night-ray.com/regex.pdf (there are better, just use google)

Answer (score 0):

/[a-zA-Z]*(/?)([a-zA-Z]*.[a-zA-Z]*)?

Tested on

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: oh, looks pretty close. checked logs and found urls like /foto/300/b/5/4/19123312.jpg. is there way to get only /foto/ too?

Answer (score 0):

or

```
  s = '/foto/300/b/5/4/19123312.jpg'
    s.split('/')[1]
     => "foto"
```